# In python how to disable Task Manager?

Tags: python, process

I tried this code but it didn't worked:

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

while True:
  subprocess.call("taskkill /F /IM Taskmgr.exe", startupinfo=si)
  sleep(1)
```

ERROR: The process "Taskmgr.exe" with PID 5220 could not be terminated.

Reason : Access denied.

Comment: Buna da ihtiyacım kalmadı.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have sufficient permissions, you should be an Administrator to kill Task Manager.

Execute `python.exe` as an Administrator. You can do this by right clicking the Python icon and then click "Run as administrator...".

Comment: I want a code will do that. (Sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import winreg


def disable_task_manager():
    # Path to the explorer properties
    registry_path: str = r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"
    # Name of the key
    registry_name: str = "DisableTaskMgr"
    # Value that the registry key is set to
    value: int = 1
    try:
        reg_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, registry_path, 0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
        winreg.SetValueEx(reg_key, registry_name, 0, winreg.REG_SZ, value)
        winreg.CloseKey(reg_key)
    except WindowsError as e:
        print("There was an error setting the registry key {}.format(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will check for and install pyuac if it is not already installed. Then it relaunches as admin and disables task manager.

```
import winreg as wrg
import pyuac
import sys
import importlib.util
import subprocess
info=[r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System',"DisableTaskMGR",1,wrg.REG_DWORD]
def checkPackage(packagename):
  name = packagename
  if name in sys.modules:
    print(f"{name!r} already in sys.modules")
  elif (spec := importlib.util.find_spec(name)) is not None:
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", name])
def runAsAdmin():
    if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
        print("Re-launching as admin!")
        pyuac.runAsAdmin()  
def changeKey():
    if pyuac.isUserAdmin():
        admin=1
    pathtokey = info[0]
    subkeyname = info[1]
    value=info[2]
    key_type=info[3]
    try:
        keyx=wrg.OpenKey(wrg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, pathtokey, 0, wrg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
        print("Key has been opened.")
    except WindowsError as e:
       print("You must run this program as administrator")
    except:
        keyx=wrg.CreateKey(wrg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, pathtokey)
    try:
        wrg.SetValueEx(keyx, subkeyname, 0, key_type, value)
        print("Key has been set.")
        wrg.CloseKey(keyx)
    except Exception as w:
       if admin==1:
          print("Error: " + str(w))
checkPackage("pyuac")
runAsAdmin()
changeKey()
```